# Convert function calling localstorage to async await

Tags: javascript, async-await

I have a url which users are returned too after signing with Auth0. When they hit this url I call `auth.handleAuthentication()`

In my React page component:

```
class AuthCallback extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    auth.handleAuthentication();
  }
```

This is the function that is called:

```
  handleAuthentication() {
    this.auth0.parseHash((err, authResult) => {
      if (authResult && authResult.accessToken && authResult.idToken) {
        this.setSession(authResult);
      } else if (err) {
        console.error(err);
      }
    });
  }

 setSession(authResult) {
    let expiresAt = JSON.stringify(
      authResult.expiresIn * 1000 + new Date().getTime(),
    );
    localStorage.setItem('access_token', authResult.accessToken);
    localStorage.setItem('AUTH_TOKEN', authResult.idToken);
    localStorage.setItem('expires_at', expiresAt);
  }
```

I need to do something asynchronously after `handleAuthentication()` and `setSession()` have finished their operation.

I tried just adding `async await` but the code seems to run synchronously.

```
class AuthCallback extends React.Component {
  async componentDidMount() {
    await auth.handleAuthentication();
    // DO STUFF
    window.location.hash = '';
    window.location.pathname = '/auth-callback-login';
  }
```

Comment: `handleAuthentication` should return a `promise`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just wrapped the function you need to await to return a promise

```
handleAuthentication() {
 return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
   this.auth0.parseHash((err, authResult) => {
     if (authResult && authResult.accessToken && authResult.idToken) {
       this.setSession(authResult);
       return resolve(authResult);
   } else if (err) {
     console.error(err);
     reject(err);
   }
  });
 });
```

Then you can do this

```
class AuthCallback extends React.Component {
  async componentDidMount() {
  await auth.handleAuthentication();
  // DO STUFF
  window.location.hash = '';
  window.location.pathname = '/auth-callback-login';
```

}

Comment: So I don't need to put setSession in a promise also?

Comment: Hey.. I don't have a comment related to this answer. Just wanted to say nice name "onecompileman" xD ~*theme music plays*~ ONE COMPILE!!!!!!!! ~*theme continues*~

Comment: Yes, @Evans since its not really doing asyncronously.

Comment: Yeah OnePunchMan reference @DeadLock :)